# Nhibernate Clear Cache for a Specific Region

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-caches

I am trying to manually clear the level 2 cache for a specific region. I found the method posted [in answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433514/nhibernate-second-level-caching-evicting-regions/11077986#11077986). While this is working to clear my entities, for some reason the querycache is not getting cleared. This results in a separate query for each entity the next time the entities are retrieved from the database. If does work when I call sessionFactory.EvictQueries() without any parameters. It is only not working when I am passing in a specific region name. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Code is from the above link:

```
private void ClearRegion(string regionName)
    {
        _sessionFactory.EvictQueries(regionName);

        foreach (var collectionMetaData in _sessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetadata().Values)
        {
            var collectionPersister = collectionMetaData as NHibernate.Persister.Collection.ICollectionPersister;
            if (collectionPersister != null)
            {
                if ((collectionPersister.Cache != null) && (collectionPersister.Cache.RegionName == regionName))
                {
                    _sessionFactory.EvictCollection(collectionPersister.Role);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var classMetaData in _sessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata().Values)
        {
            var entityPersister = classMetaData as NHibernate.Persister.Entity.IEntityPersister;
            if (entityPersister != null)
            {
                if ((entityPersister.Cache != null) && (entityPersister.Cache.RegionName == regionName))
                {
                    _sessionFactory.EvictEntity(entityPersister.EntityName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Caching is working and verified using NHProfiler.

Comment: Have you tried asking in the nhusers group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nhusers)?

Comment: Maybe you should share some code and config to see if the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out my issue. I did not realize that it is necessary to specify a cache region when querying the data, aside from specifying it in the entity mapping. After adding `.CacheRegion("regionName")` to my queries everything works. By not adding the region when querying, it was going into the query cache without a region name. That is why it worked when I called`.EvictQueries()` without a region name parameter.

To sum it up, it is necessary to add the region name when mapping the entities (`.Region("regionName")` when using Fluent) and when querying with isession using `.CacheRegion("regionName")`.

Thank you for you responses.